# Remove comma from last word using a List of String in foreach

Tags: c#-4.0

Requirement is first,second,third,forth,fifth this work fine when I use string but it doesn't works when I use foreach

```
 List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
        stringList.Add("first");
        stringList.Add("second");
        stringList.Add("third");
        stringList.Add("fourth");
        stringList.Add("fifth");

     string result = string.Join(", ", stringList).TrimEnd(',', ' ');
        Console.WriteLine(result);

    foreach (var item in stringList)
        {
            string resultt = string.Join(", ", item).TrimEnd(',', ' ');
            Console.WriteLine(resultt);
        }
```

I have to remove comma from last word from a List of string using foreach.

Comment: You don't need the `TrimEnd()` call when using `String.Join()`...

Answer (score 2):

The foreach loop iterates over each item in the list, so in your code *resultt* will always be equal to *item*. ie. resultt = item

I think you are trying to do this:

```
var resultt = "";
foreach (var item in stringList)
    {
        resultt += item + ", ";
    }
resultt = resultt.TrimEnd(',',' ');
Console.WriteLine(resultt);
```

If you are concatenating a lot of strings using StringBuilder will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the list as [first][,other][,other][,other] ... so we group the comma with the element after it, this becomes simple:

```
static String Join(string joiner, IEnumerable<String> list){
    bool first = true;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (s in list){
        if(!first){
            sb.Append(joiner);
        }else{
            first = false;
        }
        sb.Append(s);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Trim() when joining list. You just have to do it this way.

```
string mergedString = string.Join(",", stringList.ToArray());
```

There won't be any comma in the beginning nor the end of the string.